# How to run a function after $mdDialog.show while passing a variable into it?

Tags: angularjs

I want to get the $index from an element after clicking on it and then pass it through $md.Dialog.show, to visualize what I try to do:

```
<div ng-repeat="picture in card.pictures" style="background-image: url({{picture.url}})" class="user-image" ng-click="showAdvanced($event,$index,card.pictures)"></div>
```

and then I will

```
$scope.showAdvanced = function(e,i,pictures) {
      $log.log(i);
      $scope.pictures = pictures;
      $mdDialog.show({
        scope: $scope.$new(),
        controller: DialogController,
        templateUrl: 'user.details.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: e,
        clickOutsideToClose:true,
        fullscreen: false
      }).then(function(i){
        $('.lightbox-img').eq(i).focus();
      });
    };
```

I already set `.lightbox-img`'s `tabindex="0"`, but it doesn't seem to pass through.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the index to DialogController's scope through onComplete event callback.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#mddialog-show-optionsorpreset

Also, it is a really bad practice to combine jquery with angularjs. You should better user angular.element(document.querySelector()) (or document.getElementsByClassName etc).

onComplete event callback would look like this:

```
onComplete: function(scope) {scope.index = i};
```

And inside your controller you can do:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('.lightbox-img').eq(i).focus());
```